# FIRMessaging client not setup

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've search for some other question/solutions here but can't fix this issue in my App. I can't figure out what is the issue. It was working properly.

When I run my app on Actual Device or on Simulator it crashes on the splash screen. Here is the crash log.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRMessaging client not setup.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cfd71bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c0f9735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cfd6f42 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000109abc940 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   Tarfeeh                             0x0000000106e7ee9c -[FIRMessaging connectWithCompletion:] + 556
    5   Tarfeeh                             0x0000000106dcb573 $S7Tarfeeh11AppDelegateC12connectToFcmyyF + 579
    6   Tarfeeh                             0x0000000106cd900f $S7Tarfeeh11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtF + 2431
    7   Tarfeeh                             0x0000000106cd97f4 $S7Tarfeeh11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtFTo + 228
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011290ebde -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 280
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00000001129105cb -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3979
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112915c2f -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1623
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00000001121344e9 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000011213d29c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112134126 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 233
    14  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112134ae0 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1085
    15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112132cb5 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 795
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011213295f -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435
    17  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112137a90 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 584
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000011213880e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00000001121377ef -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 221
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000011213c93a -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011291444e -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00000001124b8d09 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 357
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001183da2da -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001183e5443 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 271
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001183e4b3a __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f016602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010f019b78 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000118419ba8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000118419860 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000118419e40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cf3c721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cf3bf93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cf3663f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cf35e11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001154a61dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000011291781d UIApplicationMain + 140
    37  Tarfeeh                             0x0000000106cdab44 main + 68
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f08c575 start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I just updated my podfile and it stopped working. I can't revert back to old version.

Comment: which firebase lib version you updated ?

Comment: i didn't updated firebase version. I had to add a new pod to my project so i just edited podfile and updated "pod update"

Comment: ok got it but you will get new update automatically by doing `pod update` so which version its updated can you post firebase lib version ?

Comment: how to get the exact lib version. I'm sorry I'm new to iOS.

Comment: pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’

Comment: you will get lib version from Pods.lock file.

Comment: Firebase/Core (5.15.0)  - Firebase/Messaging (5.15.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185473/discussion-between-joe-and-codechanger).

Comment: Still can't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `FirebaseApp.configure()` in Your **AppDelegate** when starting application.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```